# Can I/How do I sort titles by resolution in VLC, mplayer, or similar app?

Tags: resolution, vlc, sort

Can I/How do I sort titles by resolution in VLC, mplayer, or similar app, i.e., sort videos by their pixel count?, e.g., a 1920x1080 vid followed by a 1280x720 vid, etc, ascending or descending.